# BASH - Plug USB and shutdown automatically

Tags: usb, shutdown

I've been searching something like this but I don't find anything related.
I'd like to do this Ubuntu Linux using BASH.

1. A USB Pendrive is connected (whenever and in the ports in front of the computer, no matter which one)
2. Computer detects a USB is plugged
3. Then shutdown the computer.

This should be executing every time, every 30s more or less, the important thing is to execute the script non-stop, because there's no use if the script only executes once.

Thanks.

Comment: there is no need to have a script permanently running, udev handles device insertions/removals and it will trigger a script if it is set up appropriately. Also, it may be set not to mount the drive on insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a "USB Pendrive" or any USB device would fit? if so you may want to have a look here:

http://www.yoctopuce.com

Yoctopuce devices works with Linux, are driverless and can be detected/driven from the command line. You could use the cheapest one. You may even try to ask them if they have any [yocto-demo](http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/other-usb-modules/yocto-demo) left.

Answer (score 0):

You must try USBKILL,

an anti-forensic kill-switch that waits for a change on your USB ports and then immediately shuts down your computer.
as what is says on it. For me, this works. You just need to configure some of its settings.ini. This won't destroy your system. if you want more info, just [click here](https://github.com/hephaest0s/usbkill)